# Join table with unique values

Tags: sql-server

Below is the case, this is simple group data but join / grouping picking duplicate data....

```
CREATE TABLE #t1 (UnID bigint IDENTITY(1,1), name varchar(5), id bigint)
insert into #t1 (name,id)values('a',1)
insert into #t1 (name,id)values('a',2)
insert into #t1 (name,id)values('a',3)
insert into #t1 (name,id)values('a',4)
insert into #t1 (name,id)values('b',5)
insert into #t1 (name,id)values('c',6)

CREATE TABLE #t2 (name varchar(5), id bigint)
insert into #t2 (name,id)values('a',1)
insert into #t2 (name,id)values('a',2)
insert into #t2 (name,id)values('a',3)
insert into #t2 (name,id)values('b',4)
insert into #t2 (name,id)values('c',5)

select 
a.UnID, a.name as aName, a.Id as aId, b.Id as bId
into #t3
from #t1 a
join #t2 b on a.name = b.name

select max(bid),unid from #t3
group by UnId
```

> Grouping Result

```
bid unid
3   1
3   2
3   3
3   4
4   5
5   6
```

> Grouping desired Result

```
bid  unid
1    1
2    2
3    3
NULL 4
4    5
5    6
```

> and if bid not found then null

Comment: I'm trying to make join on two tables and want to pick next match each time. If you think there is another way of doing this then please suggest me

Comment: Excellent job posting ddl and sample data along with the desired output. What I don't understand here is the rules. Also, the query you posted returns what you status you want as desired output. If you can clarify the requirements we can help.

Comment: i'm trying to make join between two tables BUT want to pick next match if same match found. As you can see in last two group results, in first result 3-bid is matching against UnId-1 and 2.

Comment: Do you mean you don't want `bid` to be repeated if it was selected for any other `unid` once before?

Comment: That is not helping explain your requirements. What is wrong with the query you posted? Although you could skip #t3 and just write the query against the two other tables.

Comment: # Ivan Starostin yes, instead it should pick second match i.e 2

Comment: #sean Lange - grouping will compile single record for each unid and i don't want to repeat its' against bid instead want to pick second bid i.e 2, 1

Comment: if you think any other way can achieve this result then please suggest me

Answer (score 0):

Below make me possible BUT still looking for better approach, xid is extra field for holding loop value....

```
CREATE TABLE #t4 (ID bigint IDENTITY(1,1), bid bigint)

SELECT
a.UnID, a.name as aName, a.Id as aId, b.Id as bId,NULL as xid
INTO #t3
FROM #t1 a
JOIN #t2 b ONa.name = b.name

DECLARE t_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT max(bid),unid 
FROM #t3
GROUP BY UnId
DECLARE @bid bigint, @unid bigint

OPEN t_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM t_cursor 
INTO @bid, @unid
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    DECLARE @maxBid BIGINT
    SET @maxBid = 0
    SELECT @maxBid = max(bid) 
    FROM #t3 
    WHERE UnId= @unid 
    AND NOT bid IN (SELECT #t4.bid FROM #t4) GROUP BY UnId

    INSERT into #t4
    SELECT @maxBid as bid

    set @maxBid = isnull(@maxBid,0)
    if(@maxBid != 0)
    begin
        update #t3 set xid = @maxBid where unid = @unid
    end

    FETCH NEXT FROM t_cursor 
    INTO @bid, @unid
END 
CLOSE t_cursor;
DEALLOCATE t_cursor;

SELECT * FROM #t3 order by unid,bid

SELECT max(xid),unid from #t3
group by UnId
```